# Broken washer hose junction and clip hardware

Tags: ford, windshield-washer, contour, cdw27

I'm working on a 1998 Ford Contour.  The hose from the washer pump comes up on the back corner of the engine bay on the passenger side and runs across the hood toward the drivers side.  The nozzle on the passenger side connects to a plastic T-junction which is connected to the hose from the washer pump.  Another hose runs from the other side of the T-junction to the nozzle for the driver's side.  There are a few plastic clips attached to the hood to hold the hoses in place.  The T-junction and some of the clips are broken.  What's the procedure for removing broken parts?  The parts have been discontinued by Ford.  Are there any other sources for them?  Are there similar parts from another application that will work?

Comment: This question could also use pictures, especially with arrows saying "this part here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going to [Pick 'n Pull](http://www.picknpull.com/) and grabbing the junction and hoses.  The clips are really single use, it's difficult or impossible to get one out completely intact.  I visited a dealer parts department to see if they could find a clip that would work from another application and ended up with [W701117-S300](http://www.teamfordparts.com/parts/index.cfm?searchText=W701117-S300&make=Ford&action=oePartSearch&siteid=214270).  That seems to be a release cable clip for a 2012 focus.  It's a tight fit for the hose, but it fits into the hood and holds the hose in place.  I'm worried about it pinching or wearing a hole in the hose over time, but it holds to the hood much better than duct tape and the system still sprays.  There should be a diagram [here](http://www.teamfordparts.com/parts/1998/FORD/CONTOUR/LX/?siteid=214270&vehicleid=1303951&section=BODY%20HARDWARE&group=WINDSHIELD&subgroup=WIPER%20&%20WASHER%20COMPONENTS).  The broken junction is item 12.  I'm wondering if the junction and clip from a 2000 Focus might work ([linkage](http://www.teamfordparts.com/parts/2000/FORD/FOCUS/LX/?siteid=214270&vehicleid=1401163&section=BODY%20HARDWARE&group=WINDSHIELD&subgroup=WIPER%20&%20WASHER%20COMPONENTS)).  I'll check it out the next time I'm at the boneyard.